# Taking the logarithm of $e^{-x}<b$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

If I have an inequality as $e^{-x}<b$ where $b,x$ are  positive ,
can I take the logarithm on both sides and say,
$-x<=ln(b)$

Comment: Yes, since $\ln$ is monotone increasing. You can even keep the strict inequality, and it works even for $x \leq 0$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You even have 
$$
-x < \operatorname{ln}(b),
$$
because $ln \colon (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing on its entire domain.

Comment: doesn't $e^{-x}$ strictly decreasing matter?

Comment: @sam_rox No. Given two numbers $c < d$ applying a strictly increasing functions $f$ yields (by the definition of "strictly increasing") $f(c) < f(d)$. And that's all that's needed here.